# EF4.1/MVC3 Database First: How to remove password from connection string

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4.1

I'm building a website with EF4.1 and MVC3 (C#).  Trying to find out what the proper way to remove the password from the connection string is.  I've done some searching and can't seem to find anything that tells how to remove the password from the connection string.

I'm actually working on two different sites at the moment.  One is hosted on GoDaddy and is using their SQL Server db.  The other is hosted here at work and will be using SQL Server 2005.

Lastly, is it possible to do the database first code generation with a MySQL database?  I'm personally more comfortable with MySQL and prefer it to SQL Server, but have had issues getting this to work.

If you should need any additional information please let me know.

Comment: Why/where do you want to remove it?

Comment: Even if you remove it from the connection string, it still has to reside somewhere. If somebody has access to your production box, chances are there is no way to completely stop someone from getting it, you can only obfuscate it.

Comment: @SLaks Don't know... I guess that is part of the question.  I've just read on a few website that it was recommended to remove it, but none of them listed how to do so.

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich So would the only real reason to do this to keep internal eyes off of the password?  We handle government loads here at work, so security is rather important (as I think it is for most people).  I just want to make sure that I'm doing things correctly.

Comment: @Jared I'd say yes. Even internally, if somebody really wants it, they can probably get it if they have access to the box. Which is why limiting access to production boxes is so important. You can do something really weird to reduce the visibility to the database. Like only allow sprocs to run, served by a service, which is limited to incoming calls from the production IP. But even that can give out too much information if someone has access to the production box.

Comment: Does anyone have an idea on the MySQL portion of the question or should I post a new question and edit that out of this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably [encrypt your web.config connection strings](https://www.google.com/search?q=encrypt%20web%20config%20connection%20strings) before deploying it to the server.

AFAIK, if you connect to your server using SQL Server Authentication, the connection string needs the username and password. If your app and db servers had domain trust, you can use integrated mode / windows authentication / identity impersonate to have a password-less connection string. But most service providers don't let you do this -- they use SQL Server Authentication to keep customers out of their domain.

Either way, there is more sensitive information in the connection string than just the password. You should encrypt the whole `<connectionStrings>` node.

Comment: do you have any examples of HOW to do this? (or sources that I can read?)

Comment: There are examples all over the web. Click the link in my updated answer for a sample search.